# Extract a substring that starts with "http" and ends with ".mp3" from a string

Tags: python

So I read lines with urllib and it returns items with lots of information in it. I want to extract a link from each item. So I want to get the part of the string that begins with "http" and ends with ".mp3". I'm stuck.

Comment: `str.startswith, str.endswith`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for what you describe:

```
In [48]: s='Link: http://google.com/song.mp3 Another link, http://yahoo.com/another_song.mp3'

In [49]: re.findall('http.*?mp3', s)
Out[49]: ['http://google.com/song.mp3', 'http://yahoo.com/another_song.mp3']
```

Comment: Your answer seems better than mine. But I got around my problem using             

item_tosplit = item[item.index(""):]
idxhttp = item_tosplit.find('http://medias-')
idxmp3 = item_tosplit.find('.mp3') + 4
link = item_tosplit[idxhttp:idxmp3]